# Unexplained behaviour when using tail recursion

Tags: erlang, tail-recursion

I am trying to extract the even elements from a list in Erlang and i do not understand why instead of returning the resulting list it returns  `length(list)`

```
-module(rec).
-compile([debug_info]).
-export([rec/1]).


dorec(Acc,[])->Acc;
dorec(Acc,[X|Y]) when X rem 2==0 -> dorec([X|Acc],Y).


rec(X) when is_list(X)->dorec([],X);
rec(_)->"Invalid input".
```

**Usage**

```
mymodule:rec([1,2,3]). 
results: 3

mymodule:rec([2,2]).->2
results:2
```

Comment: I don't get the results you showed. I'm getting `** exception error: no function clause matching rec:dorec([],[1,2,3]) (rec.erl, line 6)` which is correct as you haven't specified the case when the when-guard is false: `dorec(Acc,[_X|Y]) -> dorec(Acc,Y)` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `rec/1` does not implement the logic you've specified. Try this:

```
-module(rec).
-compile([debug_info]).
-export([rec/1]).

% empty input
dorec(Acc,[]) -> Acc;

% uneven head is collected
dorec(Acc,[X|Y]) when X rem 2/=0 -> dorec([X|Acc],Y);

% even head is dropped
dorec(Acc,[_|Y]) -> dorec(Acc,Y).


% helper
rec(X) when is_list(X) -> dorec([],X);
rec(_) -> "Invalid input".
```

Usage and output:

```
1> c(rec). 
{ok,rec}
2> rec:rec([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]).
[9,7,5,3,1]
```

Comment: So basically the problem is that i am not doing anything when the element is un even, so at the first uneven element it will not match the guard .What i am curious is : if i already gathered a list of `[2,4,6]` in my recursive calls and now comes  an un even element ; since there will be no guard match will all the result be discarded ?

Comment: The even numbers 2, 4, 6 will never we collected. Where do you think this happens?

Comment: Sorry i changed the initial post. I wanted to collect the even elements. My question still persists: if i want to collect the even elements and so far i collected [2,4,6]  (all elements matched the guard) and then an odd element comes and i do not have a way to handle it , does my partial result get discarded?

Comment: No, it will not be discarded. The already collected numbers are in  `Acc` which is always passed as the first argument to the next call.